Syncing Google Contacts between two Google Workspace gmail ids using Google Apps Script
We have written the following code to sync contacts between two gmail ids, such that if a new contact is being added to one email id and the Google Apps Script is run, the new contacts get synced to the other email id too:
const CLIENT_ID = 'client_id'; const CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret';

// Replace with the initial refresh tokens for both users
const USER1_REFRESH_TOKEN = 'Reftoken1';
const USER2_REFRESH_TOKEN = 'Reftoken2';

function syncContacts() {
  try {
    // Get fresh access tokens for both users
    const user1AccessToken = refreshAccessToken(USER1_REFRESH_TOKEN);
    const user2AccessToken = refreshAccessToken(USER2_REFRESH_TOKEN);

    // Fetch contacts from both accounts
    const user1Contacts = fetchContacts(user1AccessToken);
    const user2Contacts = fetchContacts(user2AccessToken);

    // Sync contacts between accounts
    addUniqueContacts(user1Contacts, user2AccessToken);
    addUniqueContacts(user2Contacts, user1AccessToken);

    Logger.log('Contacts synced successfully!');
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error during sync: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

function fetchContacts(accessToken) {
  const url = 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?pageSize=2000&personFields=names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers';
  const options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };

  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200 && result.connections) {
      Logger.log(`Fetched ${result.connections.length} contacts.`);
      return result;
    } else {
      Logger.log('Error fetching contacts: ' + response.getContentText());
      return null;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error fetching contacts: ' + error.message);
    return null;
  }
}


function addUniqueContacts(sourceAccessToken, targetAccessToken) {
  const sourceContacts = fetchContacts(sourceAccessToken);
  const targetContacts = fetchContacts(targetAccessToken);

  if (!sourceContacts || !targetContacts) {
    Logger.log('Failed to fetch contacts. Aborting synchronization.');
    return;
  }

  const targetPhoneNumbers = new Set(
    targetContacts.connections.flatMap(contact =>
      contact.phoneNumbers?.map(phone => formatPhoneNumber(phone.value)) || []
    )
  );

  const uniqueContacts = sourceContacts.connections.filter(contact =>
    (contact.phoneNumbers || []).some(phone =>
      !targetPhoneNumbers.has(formatPhoneNumber(phone.value))
    )
  );

  Logger.log(`Found ${uniqueContacts.length} unique contacts.`);

  uniqueContacts.forEach(contact => {
    const sanitizedContact = sanitizeContact(contact); // Sanitize before creating
    try {
      createContact(targetAccessToken, sanitizedContact);
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log('Error adding unique contact: ' + error.message);
    }
  });
}

function sanitizeContact(contact) {
  // Remove metadata, resourceName, etag, and other unnecessary fields
  return {
    names: contact.names?.map(name => ({
      displayName: name.displayName,
      givenName: name.givenName,
    })),
    emailAddresses: contact.emailAddresses?.map(email => ({
      value: email.value,
    })),
    phoneNumbers: contact.phoneNumbers?.map(phone => ({
      value: phone.value,
    })),
  };
}

function createContact(accessToken, contact) {
  const url = 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact';
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify(contact),
  };

  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
      Logger.log('Contact Created: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
    } else {
      Logger.log('Error creating contact: ' + response.getContentText());
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error creating contact: ' + error.message);
    throw new Error('Failed to create contact.');
  }
}

        function refreshAccessToken(refreshToken) {
  const url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';
  const payload = {
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    refresh_token: refreshToken,
    grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  };

   const options = {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    payload: Object.keys(payload)
      .map((key) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(payload[key])}`)
      .join('&'),
    muteHttpExceptions: true, // Capture full error details
  };

  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    // Log the response for debugging
    Logger.log(`Token refresh response: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`); 

     if (result.access_token) {
      Logger.log('Access token refreshed successfully.');
      return result.access_token;
    } else {
      throw new Error(result.error_description || 'Failed to refresh access token.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`Error refreshing access token: ${error.message}`);
    throw new Error('Access token refresh failed.');
  }
} 

         function formatPhoneNumber(phone) {
  // Standardize phone numbers for comparison
  return phone.replace(/[^\d+]/g, ''); // Removes non-digit and non-'+' characters
}


However, I keep getting this error:
Error fetching contacts: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}

These are the following ways I have tried trouble shooting:

Check if People API is enabled for both email ids.

Set up Credentials from one account and share with the other.

Set up these following redirect URI's:
http://localhost, https://script.google.com/oauthcallback, https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

Have authorised API in Google playground from both id's and stored correct refresh tokens


I am not sure how to rectify this error. Would be really helpful if someone could guide?

Could you be more specific? 1. Did you get the access token or the refresh token? 2. Why not just use advanced Google services or 3. ScriptApp.getOauthToken() ?
